# Pandas Counting Each Column with its Spesific Thresholds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a following dataframe:

```
          A       B       C       D       E

1         1       2       0       1       0
2         0       0       0       1      -1
3         1       1       3      -5       2
4        -3       4       2       6       0
5         2       4       1       9      -1
T         1       2       2       4       1
```

The last row is my threshold values for each column. I want to count each column values whether lower its threshold values or not  in python pandas.

Desired Output is;

```
         A       B       C       D       E
Count    2       2       3       3       4
```

But, I need to figure it out with a general solution, not for these specific columns. Because I have a large dataset. I cannot specify a column name for each of them in the code.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all rows without first by indexing and compare by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) by last row, then `sum` and convert `Series` to one row `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:-1].lt(df.iloc[-1]).sum().to_frame('count').T
print (df)
       A  B  C  D  E
count  2  2  3  3  4
```

Numpy alternative with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
arr = df.values
df = pd.DataFrame([np.sum(arr[:-1] < arr[-1], axis=0)], columns=df.columns, index=['count'])
print (df)
       A  B  C  D  E
count  2  2  3  3  4
```